# How to follow javascript:GO(123456) hrefs to get to new URLs while webscraping?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to create a webscraper to parse different tennis tournaments and am trying to follow href links to get to pages with more info for each tourney. I am currently using Scrapy and have done tasks like this before but usually under href tags I find actual urls to simply follow. Now I am finding things like , and am having trouble figuring out how to make the scraper follow this.

I have found a quite a few sites detaling Scrapy and how it isn't as effective with javascript, and have started to follow potential solutions with Selenium of which I am very new to. The issue is that none of these are doing the same thing as I need, unless they explain at a very high level I need to 'inspect the javascript and follow it from there from Selenium' (which I am lost trying to figure out).

Here is the link to the base website I am scraping from (with my command to open a scrapy shell to the site):

```
scrapy shell https://m.tennislink.usta.com/TournamentSearch/SearchResults.aspx?typeofsubmit=&Action=2&Keywords=&TournamentID=&SectionDistrict=&City=&State=&Zip=&Month=1&StartDate=&EndDate=&Day=&Year=2019&Division=G8&Category=&Surface=&OnlineEntry=&DrawsSheets=&UserTime=&Sanctioned=-1&AgeGroup=Y&SearchRadius=-1
```

Then getting at the table data tags with href attributes (half are google map links I will be ignoring, but the other half are the links I want to figure out and follow):

```
table = response.css('td> a::attr(href)')
```

Here is an example of the output from here:

```
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::td/a/@href' data='http://maps.google.com/maps?q=30 Snyders'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::td/a/@href' data='javascript:Go(229689);'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::td/a/@href' data='http://maps.google.com/maps?q=60 Sea Cli'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::td/a/@href' data='javascript:Go(229805);'>]
```

But following this I cannot simply use

```
response.urljoin(next_page_URL_stub)
```

where next_page_URL_stub is the URL I am missing like I usually would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would require either evaluating the Javascript (which is what modern search engines do) to find the actual resulting link (which might not be a link, it could be an in-page retrieval of new content to replace the old one).

However, if you look at the source code, you can see that the Javascript in question for the link you gave above is:

```
function Go(iTournamentID) {
    var oForm = document.forms[0];
    window.location = '../TournamentHome/Tournament.aspx?T=' + iTournamentID;
}
```

You can use that to perform a hard replace using the id given in the Go()-call above, for example by adding a check to see if it starts with the Javascript call and then extract the id (the len() call will start the extracting at the character after `(` and then drop the two last chars (`;)`):

```
if next_page_URL_stub.startswith('javascript:Go('):
    next_page_URL_stab = '../TournamentHome/Tournament.aspx?T=' + next_page_URL_stub[len('javascript:Go(')]:-2]
```

This should be urljoinable with your previous URL.

Comment: This is awesome; thank you so much. Don't have enough reputation to upscore but will come back and do so sap.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but can you share how you found the javascript source code? I opened up all the tags I could find and searched for the function Go but to no success... Is there a method to this or just guessing and checking?

Comment: Just 'view source' in my browser and search for `Go(`.

Answer (score 0):

Just construct needed URL by yourself.

```
url_template = 'https://m.tennislink.usta.com/TournamentHome/Tournament.aspx?T={}'
url_ids = response.css('a::attr(href)').re('Go\((\d+)\)')

for url_id in url_ids:
    next_page_url = url_template.format(url_id)
```